# Find some shapes by name, other shapes by specific color and delete them

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a few presentations with shapes I need to delete, with

- specific .Name
- specific color

Those shapes with specific .Name can be grouped (*not in my code*). I found code in stackoverflow and tried to modify it.

1. Find shape by name and delete it: Specific .Name can be "XXName1" as well "Name1".

If there are no shapes with `.Name = "Name1"` I get an Error

> "Object does not exist"

on the line `If .Name = "Name1" Or .Name = "Name2" Then`

Sometimes the code works, and then, if there are a lot slides in the presentation,  I have an error.
When I test with a 1-slide presentation - no error.

2. Find shape by color and delete it:

I have an Error

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

I don't understand how to declare variable

```vb
Sub DeleteShapes()
    Dim oSld   As Slide
    Dim oShp   As Shape
    Dim oshpGroup As Shape
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim str As String
        
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For L = oSld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            With oSld.Shapes(L)
            ' Find shape by name and delete it
                If .Name = "XXName1" Or .Name = "XXName2" Then
                    .Delete
                End If
                If .Name = "Name1" Or .Name = "Name2" Then
                    .Delete
                End If
                
                ' Find shape by color and delete it            
                If oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Or _
                  oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1) Or _
                  oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(2, 2, 2) Or _
                  oShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(3, 3, 3) Then
                    oShp.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next L
    Next oSld
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the instances of `oShp`... you want to refer back to `With osld.Shapes(L)`.

Comment: @BigBen do you mean the changes like below? If so, I have an error "Object required"
                If .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Or _
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1) Or _
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(2, 2, 2) Or _
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(3, 3, 3) Then
                        .Delete
                End If

Comment: Something like that yes.

Comment: I have an error "Object required" then :(

Comment: You can't refer to a shape after you've deleted it (which you've done previously). Change your sequential `If...End If`, `If...End If` to `If...ElseIf....ElseIf...End If`.

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks, it works!

Comment: Great! Feel free to post it as an answer to your question, so that the question shows as answered for future readers.

Comment: I would love to, but I'm trying to find where is the green "answered" mark, can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't refer to a shape after you've deleted it (which you've done
> previously). Change your sequential If...End If, If...End If to
> If...ElseIf....ElseIf...End If. – @BigBen

My revised code:

```
Sub DeleteShapes()
    Dim oSld   As Slide
    Dim oShp   As Shape
    Dim L As Long
    
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For L = oSld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            With oSld.Shapes(L)
                If .Name = "XXName1" Or .Name = "XXName2" Then
                    .Delete
                ElseIf .Name = "Name1" Or .Name = "Name2" Then
                    .Delete
                ElseIf .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                    .Delete
                ElseIf .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1) Then
                    .Delete
                ElseIf .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(2, 2, 2) Then
                    .Delete
                ElseIf .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(3, 3, 3) Then
                        .Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next L
    Next oSld
End Sub
```